# Fallback with dropzone.js : file selected, not uploading

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm experiencing a problem with the otherwise excellent http://www.dropzonejs.com/

The upload works ok with modern browser, but when I test the fallback, the file is selectable via modal dialog, but not uploaded.

```
<div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
</div>
```

Does this mean that I've to deploy my own custom upload codefor the fallback? I mean, should I write something like..

```
$("#dropzoneImage .fallback").change(function(event){

                     //var jqxhr = $.ajax({...
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you left your fallback html away dropzonejs will create it by itself properly so you don't need it to code by your own.

What's missing in you `form` is most probably the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` 
which is required by older browsers - yes we speak about the old school ;)